# Return Number of arrays in LocalStorage Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, localhost

So I know there's been plenty of other posts similar to this one, but I've looked through them all and I keep getting the ***Json length*** instead of the number of arrays.

I've tried

```
function getLength(obj) {
  return (Object.values(obj)).flat().length
}
```

```
const lenObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storeObj'));
var count = 0;
for(var item in lenObj) {
   count += lenObj[item].length
}
console.log("JSON obj length: ",count);
```

```
localStorage.keyname.length
```

This is my Key, Notification, in LocalStorage:

```
[{"id":1,"user":2},{"id":2,"user":2},{"id":6,"user":2},{"id":11,"user":2},{"id":12,"user":2},{"id":13,"user":2}]
```

Currently no matter what method of length I try, I keep getting a value of **112** instead of **6**

Here's my code:

```
 methods: {
    localStorage() {
      localStorage.setItem("Notification", JSON.stringify(this.notifications));
      console.log("works");
      console.log(this.notifications);
    }
  },
 getNames: function() {
      this.names = localStorage.getItem("Notification");
      console.log(this.names);
      *~code to return 6~*
    },
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Notification") || ' [{"id": 1, "user": 2}, {"id": 2, "user": 2}, {"id": 6, "user": 2}, {"id": 11, "user": 2}, {"id": 12, "user": 2}, {"id": 13, "user": 2}]');
if (Array.isArray(data)) {//save into localStorage only if data is an array
    localStorage.setItem("Notification", JSON.stringify(data));
    let Notification = localStorage.getItem("Notification");
    let array_Notification = JSON.parse(Notification);
    console.log(Notification.length);//this will return 112, because it's a string
    console.log(array_Notification.length);//this will return 6 because it's an array
}else{
    localStorage.removeItem("Notification"); //something is not right , it's better to remove that dummy data
}
```

Comment: This almost works, but if I set data equal to the 'localStorage.getItem' data the code fails. They should be the same thing, so I'm not sure why only writing the data out would run correctly

Comment: @yetiblue `localStorage.setItem` - expects a string so you need to convert your array to string `JSON.stringify` will to that for you `localStorage.getItem` will return string or null and you need to converted back to array

Comment: @yetiblue I think you have `JSON.stringify` your data more than once and when you parse it it's still a string. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are making the solution more complicated than it needs to be. If your notifications look like that array of objects, then - without storage - it's as simple as a parse on the json string and asking for the length of the parsed object.

```js
let json = '[{"id":1,"user":2},{"id":2,"user":2},{"id":6,"user":2},{"id":11,"user":2},{"id":12,"user":2},{"id":13,"user":2}]';
let data = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(data.length);
```

So your `getNames` method would look something like:

```
getNames: () => {
   this.names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Notification")); // array of objects
   return this.names.length; // return 6
}
```

Comment: Hmm yeah this seems to work, but how could I get the array into a string? Without them, JSON.parse returns a  'Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1' error.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` will turn an object into a string value. `JSON.parse` turns the string back into an object. The error you have here usually occurs when the string data is not a valid JSON format.

Comment: I think parsing works, it just threw an error when I tried to console log the variable right after. If you look at the answer above: 'let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Notification")' console logging 'data' right after this line would make it fail, but with the if statement logic  it works.

Comment: The data in your local storage was malformatted. It was a parsing error. That's why the `if` statement works in the other answer. Because some bad data was saved in storage. So you remove it. Then the next time it saves, it should be in the correct format and no error. You should be good to go now.